# Charge Pump Inverter Noise

Tags: charge-pump

I'm using an Charge Pump Inverter,MAX899R in free run mode with switching frequency of **500kHz** like in the circuit attached. The problem is that I'm seeing a lot of switching  noise in the output, much more than i expected as it is visible in the figure attached. Moreover the noise has a frequency of 1MHz, and not 500 KHz, is this normal ?  How could i fix the problem ?

[image: Switching Noise]

[image: Circuit]

***Update***
After a suggestion of AndyAka, I checked the ground and it has the noise I'm seeing in the output, I read it would improve to use a ferrite bead after GND and after VCC but no improvements. I'm adding 3 more pictures with the noise at the ground(fig1), noise in the VCC with osciloscoppe earth probe closer to C11(fig2) and the noise in VCC with earth probe closer to C20.

**Ground Signal** 
[image: Noise At GND]

**VCC with with osciloscope earth probe closer to C20** 
[image]

**VCC with with osciloscope earth probe closer to C11** 
[image]

Comment: Where have you got the earth side of the scope probe? Two edges per 500 kHz will look like 1 MHz.

Comment: The earth of my probe is connect to the GND.

Comment: But how close to C20 and, if you have the probe earth and tip grounded at the same point do you still see stuff?

Comment: How does your layout look? C19 and C20 should have very short but wide traces to the associated pins of the IC.

Comment: @Andyaka You are right, i moved the probe earth closer to the capacitor ground and the noise got greatly removed. Now i have around 500mVp swing. I add several capacitors of 100nF at output in paralel but there was no significant improvement. Do you have any tip ?

Comment: @Grebu I'm prototyping right now so i«m using a breadboard :(

Comment: That means a lot of rather long wires and component legs, which could increases your inductance. Adding to what @owg60 pointed out. Try to put the capacitors very close to the IC and keep the legs short. Maybe this helps further after following owg60's answer.

Comment: If you short the probe tip to probe earth and leave the probe earth still connected what do you see. Also, can you explain the sizes of signals before and after when you moved the earth closer to the output capacitor.

Comment: @Andyaka I shorted and i see the same noise I'm seeing at the output. I updated the original post with three screenshots of the GND and VCC closer and far from the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background: -

> If you short the probe tip to probe earth and leave the probe earth
>   still connected what do you see? - Andyaka
>
> @Andyaka I shorted and i see the same noise I'm seeing at the output.

The basic problem here is your scope is picking up a signal in the loop formed with its ground connection. You need to use a better probe or a differential measurement. Here's apicture from TI that explains the problem: -

[image]

The picture was taken from [Understanding, Measuring, and Reducing Output Voltage Ripple](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/simple_switcher/w/simple_switcher_wiki/2243.understanding-measuring-and-reducing-output-voltage-ripple) by Texas Instruments and covers the issue of good scope probing techniques.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem here is the self resonance of the output capacitor.  Try putting smaller capacitors in parallel with it.  At the noise frequencies in your scope photo, the 22uF capacitor is looking like and inductor.